# Is there a way to lock the difficulty setting in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft, difficulty settings can be changed anytime, and this is in fact (normally) a great feature. Yet, for some reasons given below, I am looking for an option to disable this feature, may it be by a mod or whatever. Does anybody know a way to lock the difficulty setting once a game is created? Or even better (for my purposes): How can I enforce that new games will always use a predetermined, fixed difficulty that cannot be changed?

*Some explanation:* I have seen many discussions of such a question in the web being stalled by comments like "Aww, man, just show some willpower and don't switch the setting!" In the problem at hand, I am preparing a (single-player) installation of Minecraft for my niece and nephew. They love the game, but they are quite young, and being attacked by a bunch of scary spiders will most certainly lead to severe nightmares, that much I am sure. Hence, I want to technically prevent them from changing the difficulty (either on purpose or by accident) to something other than "peaceful". So please, consider this question as valid.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, I can't find a mod.

Comment: I know what you mean about giving them nightmares, *I* sometimes get nightmares!

Comment: Simply tell them that if they change the difficulty, a monster will come and blow up their house.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A slight work around, that would probably be better as it will turn of mobs but keep health regen off, would be to run the game on a server. You would not need a spare computer as you can run it off the same PC as the game. All you need to do is change:

> spawn-monsters=true

To:

> spawn-monsters=false

In the server's server.properties file. If you are worried about them *purposely* changing it back you can lock the file to admin access, although if you do this they will not be able to change map.

Comment: Was exactly my first thought. Additionally you can write-protect the `saves` folder in `~/.minecraft/` (or similar...at least on a half decent operating system) to keep them from starting a singleplayer world. Though, I'd check if you have a spare computer for the server, it doesn't even need to be something fancy, any machine with 2GiB RAM will do (my private server is running on an Intel Atom).

Comment: This is currently (1.8) bugged.  Spawners will still spawn even with `spawn-monsters` set to `false`.  The only way I could disable them was to turn off health regen also (i.e. set `difficulty=0`).

Comment: You'd need a pretty powerful computer to run both a server and a client though (er... okay, so my laptop can't do it... I imagine if you have a decent desktop, this should work)

Comment: @Unionhawk Playing single player is basically running the server locally, it's just more memory efficient. With 4 GB of RAM you're actually fine to run a server while running [two instances of the game (one in a VM for multiseat gaming)](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/14845/88)

Comment: @Zommuter Then my issue was the "with 4 GB of RAM" bit.

Comment: I ran the server and the client with 1.86GB of RAM

Answer (score 1):

After they start a level, immediately ask them to say:

```
/gamerule doMobSpawn false
```

or set their difficulty to Peaceful. Only hard can be locked, which cannot be simple and is only locked automatically on Hardcore.