# Two monitors, but can't play and use the mouse at the same time on both screens

Tags: monitor, mouse

I have a problem.

I just bought a monitor that i plugged to my gaming laptop.
My problem is that i would like to play on one monitor with an Xbox controller, while using my external mouse on my second screen.
The problem comes from the fact that the game recognizes the mouse, so even if i try to use it on my first screen, it's gonna disapear and go in game on the second screen.

I've tried the dual monitor tools to lock the mouse on one screen, but it doesn't change anything : when i start gaming on the other screen, the mouse goes into the game and disappears from the first screen.
I've tried to seperate the screens in the display settings of windows, but the same problem happens as soon as i start to play.

Is there a way to solve that ?

Thanks !

Comment: There are actually very few games that support using the mouse on another screen while playing. Among those that do support it, most will lose focus (you can't control the game any more) as soon as you click anywhere outside the game.

Comment: This is going to vary from game to game. Some don't capture the mouse at all, some may allow it to escape only in windowed mode, some may require you to pause the game or even Alt+Tab out of it, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Achieving what you want on a simple Windows PC directly is going to be difficult and some games may exclusively grab devices anyway and prevent you from doing this. However, if you are willing to spend a large amount of time configuring things, it's definitely possible with more complicated setups.

[Check out this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14202/multiseat-gaming/375836#375836). It details 'multi-seat gaming' which is actually going to achieve what you want via VMs or multi-box software: one 'seat' will have your mouse, while another can have the controller. The game won't see the other input device and therefore can't grab it.Each seat has its own monitor and focus and you can therefore control multiple applications simultaneously.